# Views API - how to replace PHP fields

Tags: 6, views

So a client that I inherited has multiple PHP fields in each of their views.

I'd like to replace them. They're using PHP Code module as well as Views Customfield.

Would I have to write a custom views handler? Or is there some sort of alter that would allow me to basically replace each of these fields/data sources with my own information, without exposing a PHP filter to a user (even an admin user).

Basically I am trying to increase site security.

Comment: Yes, a custom views handler is the way to go. There's a great example at https://gist.github.com/juampy72/5816530 on how to implement one.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I usually use:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

For pre-processing the views render array.